# Symfony2 restful routing like rails

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to do routing for an e-commerce site, here is the RESTful route I want..

```
/Category
/Category/1
/Category/1/Product
/Category/1/Product/1
```

This is what I have got so far...

```
test_index_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: TestIndexBundle:Default:index }
test_index_product:
    pattern: /category/{cat_id}/product/{prod_id}
    defaults: { _controller: TestIndexBundle:Product:index, cat_id : 1, prod_id : 1 }
test_index_category:
    pattern: /category/{cat_id}
    defaults: { _controller: TestIndexBundle:Category:index, cat_id : 1 }
```

I can access all the urls above but /Category and /Category/1/Product is actually working like /Category/1 and /Category/1/Product/1 because of the default value 1. So how should I make them able to show all categories and all products under category like.

```
/Category <-- all categories available
/Category/1/Product <-- all products under category 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following after the homepage route:

```
test_all_category:
    pattern: /category
    defaults: { _controller: TestIndexBundle:Category:index }

test_all_products_for_category:
    pattern: /category/{cat_id}/product
    defaults: { _controller: TestIndexBundle: Product:index }
```

just note that this way the cat_id will be null for test_category_all and prod_id will be null for test_all_products_for_category so you'll need to check for that.

Comment: Got this error ... Controller "Test\IndexBundle\Controller\CategoryController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$cat_id" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

Comment: oh so I set the cat_id to NULL like this in controller 
public function indexAction($cat_id = NULL) is it correct?

Comment: actually I could even use different action in controller. Thanks!